# Why is Controller reinitialised when model updates?

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

Below is a small toy version of my problem.

So I have a controller (coffeescript):

```
Test.PriceController = Em.ObjectController.extend
    init: ->
        this._super();
        console.log 'initialized'
```

And a model:

```
Test.Price = DS.Model.extend
    cost:        DS.attr 'string'
```

And the price model updates every 5 seconds from a data source. Every time the model updates, the console.log in the init of the controller is triggered. Can't seem to see in the ember docs whether this is the correct behaviour or not. Thing is, I'd like to add a property to the controller that stores the last "cost" value, but given that the object keeps being reinitialised, this would be wiped when the model updates. Also, if this is correct behaviour, any alternative approaches to this would be appreciated.

To summarise: why does the controller act like this, and if it is by design, what is the correct way to store the "last cost" variable like I've outlined above?

Comment: how are you updating the model?

Comment: I hit JSON API in my Adapter's find(), then Serializer munges the JSON a bit in extractSingle() before calling @_super. Ember takes care of the rest, I don't explicitly update the model.

Comment: so you're calling `find` again and the model is updating underneath.  Is the model in a collection and the price controller being used as an item controller?

Comment: yes, output in the view is {{#each price itemController='price'}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are making use of an `itemController` for each price, the reinitialization you're finding is indeed by design. Since the price objects are getting replaced instead of their properties just being updated, the virtual controller that the `{{each}}` helper creates has no choice but to create new instances of item controllers to wrap each object.
See this part of the array controller source that shows this behavior:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.5.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/controllers/array_controller.js#L219

The reason this doesn't happen with an `ObjectController` attached to a route is that non-item controllers are long-lived singletons throughout the life of your application.

As for how you can approach this problem, I suggest keeping longer-lived state in your `PricesController` (your `ArrayController`) and simply having the item controllers reference that state using the `needs` API. It is useful to know that item controllers are full-fledged controllers and have access to other controllers if need be. Check out this example here:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mivoh/2/edit?html,js,output